# How to click save password notification in puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm having a problem handling puppeteer's notifications. I want to save the login info so that the browser can autofill it when I open a new tab but I can't find a way or a command line that supports clicking save when this window shows up. or something like that so when I open a new tab the autofill will work without me having to retype it. help me please. thank you. My English is not good, I apologize if people find it difficult to understand.

[image: notifications image]

Comment: Why did you need this feature? I guess the password is already saved in your "code".

Comment: does pressing escape get rid of this? you can simulate pressing the relevant keys

Comment: @hoangdv i need auto fill form login when open new tab

Answer (score 0):

To save password, you can include the "**--enable-save-password-bubble**" argument in your code like this.

```
            browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                headless:false,
                executablePath:"Your path",  
                defaultViewport: null,
                ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
                devtools: true,
                userDataDir:'Your Path'
                ignoreDefaultArgs: [''],
                args: [
                    '--enable-save-password-bubble',
                ]
```

"Make sure you remember to specify the path for your public profile's **userDataDir** when running the program, as this will ensure that your saved password is stored in your profile folder."